# Вслух скажу: «Где же годы, друг?» — про себя :/— «Где же песня, брат?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> Вслух скажу: «Где же годы, друг?» — про себя: «Где же песня, брат?

> Вслух скажу: «Где же годы, друг?» — про себя — «Где же песня, брат?»